# Юлий Цезарь — человек, изменивший Древний Рим. Сегментированная конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Вот пример заголовка видео:

> Юлий Цезарь — человек, изменивший Древний Рим

Это двусоставное предложение или сегментированная конструкция? Больше похоже на сегментированную конструкцию (голос после первой части понижается и делается более длительная пауза).
Сравним с другим примером:

> "Матросы — преторианцы революции"

Этот пример больше походит на "обычное" двусоставное предложение.

В подобных заголовках всё по-разному от случая к случаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы отнесла оба предложения к двусоставным. У сегментации есть свои узнаваемые черты:

l.   Синтаксическое и интонационное выделение части высказывания (сегмента). *Юлий Цезарь — человек, изменивший Древний Рим*. Сегмент здесь был бы ***Юлий Цезарь***, на него  должно падать фразовое ударение, но мне хочется выделить вторую часть, чтобы выделить первую, я бы поставила точку, оформила бы как именительный темы: *Юлий Цезарь. Человек, изменивший Древний Рим*

2.При сегментации в рамках одного простого предложения **обязательно присутствует слово (сегмент) и заменяющее его местоимение.** Здесь местоимения нет.

Графическое обозначение сегментации

Х – он (его) х1.
Х, он х1.

Х (глагол) - такое х1.

**Разновидности сегментации**

Конструкции с сегментированным существительным

1. Конструкции с согласованным анафорическим местоимением: местоимение в том же падеже, что и заменяемое им слово

Тинькофф – он такой один.

2. Конструкции с согласованным существительным в косвенных падежах

Мужа – его дома нет.

3. Именительный темы – Им.п. называет предмет или явление, а речь о нем идет дальше.

Любовь. Она бывает разной.

Делиберативный оборот – конструкция для выделения темы сообщения.

Что касается чего; что до - то

Что до власти – то она всегда на месте.

Что касается детей, то их уложили раньше.

Конструкции с сегментированным глаголом

Пересмотреть все спектакли мастера, такое удается нечасто.

Так что я здесь сегментирования не вижу. Можно, конечно, расценить первое предложение как номинативное, распространённое приложением, но ведь это тоже не сегментирование. Сегментированием было бы такое предложение:
*Юлий Цезарь — он человек, изменивший Древний Рим.*